# How to change date formet using Python?

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I want to change date format using Python. I don't know How to do that.
I have date format as shown below

```
2020-10-22 12:14:41.293000+00:00
```

I want to change above date format into below format:

```
date(2020, 10, 22)
```

I want this format because I want to get different between two dates.

 with  above format I can get difference by using following code,

```
d0 = date(2017, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2017, 10, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)
```

So how to Change date Format as I discussed above.and also let me know if anyone know other way to get difference between these two dates `2020-10-22 12:14:41.293000+00:00` and `2020-10-25 12:14:41.293000+00:00` without changing its formet.I will be thankful if anyone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

use `fromisoformat` and `date()` to get only the date, without the time:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-10-22 12:14:41.293000+00:00').date()
# d
# datetime.date(2020, 10, 22)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a datetime object, we use the `datetime` module.

```
from datetime import datetime

def str_to_date(s):
    s = s.split()[0] # Separate the str by spaces and get the first item (the date)
    s = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return s # You now have a datetime object to do operations on.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always in the form `YYYY-MM-DD .....` then you can strip the first 10 characters of the date and use datetime to convert into datetime object

```
from datetime import datetime 

unformatted_date = "2020-10-22 12:14:41.293000+00:00"
date_obj = datetime.strptime(unformatted_date[0:11], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(date_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change string to datetime format:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime('2020-10-22 12:14:41.293000+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z').date()
date2 = datetime.strptime('2020-10-23 12:14:41.293000+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z').date()

print(date2-date1)

#1 day, 0:00:00
```